# How to extend signup model of django-allauth and add firstname and lastname fields?

Tags: python, django

I am using django-allauth app and to extend user model I added firstname and lastname in `models.py` as below:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

then added its associated form in `forms.py` within `accounts` app:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'username')
```

finally customized  the `urls.py` file within `accounts` app and added a view to use customized above stated form and model:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignupView.as_view(), name='sign_up'),
]
```

and in views:

```
class SignupView(CreateView):
    model = CustomUser
    form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'
```

I passed the form in template and it is not showing firstname and lastname fields.

Comment: Add `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'appname.CustomUser'` inside settings.py.

Comment: For extending user model you can refer [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html).

Comment: I already added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.CustomUser'`, inspite of it, it doesn't work